# Unicode characters from JSON.stringify to real unicode characters

Tags: php, json, utf

I use `JSON.stringify()` function to stringify JS objects for AJAX sending to PHP.

The problem arises when JSON.stringify function encodes unicode characters to format `\uxxxx` (eg. `\u000a`). My question is how to convert those characters to regular unicode characters in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output UTF-16? A little stuck.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506988/output-utf-16-a-little-stuck)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Output UTF-16? A little stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506988/output-utf-16-a-little-stuck/3508040#3508040)

This converts to UTF-8:

```
function unescape_utf16($string) {
    /* go for possible surrogate pairs first */
    $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/\\\\u(D[89ab][0-9a-f]{2})\\\\u(D[c-f][0-9a-f]{2})/i',
        function ($matches) {
            $d = pack("H*", $matches[1].$matches[2]);
            return mb_convert_encoding($d, "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE");
        }, $string);
    /* now the rest */
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i',
        function ($matches) {
            $d = pack("H*", $matches[1]);
            return mb_convert_encoding($d, "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE");
        }, $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in ...

Error in the code.

Comment: @Stazh You are using PHP < 5.3. It's easy to work around, just define named functions and pass a string with their name to preg_replace_callback.