# String array on JSON.stringify outputs unicode characters

Tags: javascript, java, json, unicode, stringify

I'm trying to send a string array as a parameter on a get request.

```
console.log(arrayOfStrings); //Prints ["28"]
var ids = JSON.stringify(arrayOfStrings);
console.log(ids); //Prints ["\u00002\u00008"]   

$http.get('do_staff_search', { params:{'ids': ids } }).then(successHandler);
```

However, when I stringify the number array, I get `["\u00002\u00008"]` which then causes an error on the server `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "▯2▯8"` with the two rectangular blocks in front of each number.

If I use Google Chrome's console, create the same array and stringify it, the output is `"["28"]"`

This seems like a trivial issue, but I couldn't find a good similar question on Stack Overflow.

**UPDATE**

I did some tests and it turns out @MinusFour is correct. It is an array of strings, not an array of integers as I assumed (the array is the payload from another request).

**UPDATE 2**

I tried converting the string array to an integer array using this function:

```
function arrayOfNums(arr){
    var  newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
    };
    return newArr;
}
```

But parse Int is returning NaN for each element. Now i'm wondering if there is some encoding issue with my strings that cold be causing it, since I got them from a server request I made earlier. I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424919/chrome-parseint-returns-nan) but I'm not sure how I would escape any invalid characters.

Just as some background, the array is stored as a CLOB on an SQL DB. I'm using Spring and Jackson on the server side to send a JSON object back, and within this object I have the array in question. Although I have access to the code on the server, I can't really change it because there are other applications that make requests to it.

Comment: are you creating this array hard-coded like this `[28]` ? (like the code you shared)

Comment: Welll, I'm getting `"[28]"` on Firefox, which environment are you using?

Comment: Looks there is something with editor you wrote code. Like you have invisible special characters.

Comment: Well, looks like you have this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862430/differences-in-json-stringify-result-between-browsers

Comment: @Hacketo, the code is simplified. The array is is stored in a variable.

Comment: @PedroHoehlCarvalho, well since this isn't the real code we can't find the real problem. My best guess would be that the element of the array is not a number, but a string. Again, nobody will be able to tell, because we don't have the real code.

Comment: Does your simplified example produce the same problem when you run it? If not then you need to prude an example that does demonstrate the problem.

Comment: HI @bhspencer, Thank you for commenting on your downvote. Since MinusFour's comment, I've updated the question to reflect the actual problem. It seems to be a problem with the strings I'm getting from the server (which I couldn't possibly demonstrate here), but I'll try to update the question as I get new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the strings are coming with some invalid characters back from the AJAX request as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424919/chrome-parseint-returns-nan)

So before running the array through `JSON.stringify`, I'm cleaning each string up like this:

```
function arrayOfNums(arr){
    var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
    var  newArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = parseInt(arr[i].match( numberPattern ).join(""));
    };
    return newArr;
}
```

Because there are invalid characters in front of each digit, I use join to concatenate all digits together after matching the pattern.

More of a work around than a permanent solution, I just hope this helps someone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think your question is bit confusing!

It might be giving because you are applying `JSON.stringify()` on `string` array.. that's what i am seeing in your code.. (please check!)

make change: try to change it to an `integer` array

for example this:

```
arrayOfStrings = [28];
```

and then check!

Below is just an other example i tested:

```
var test_arr = [1, 2, 3, 5]; // array of integers
console.log(test_arr); // will print: [1, 2, 3, 5] -- an integer array

var test_ids = JSON.stringify(test_arr);
console.log(test_ids); // // will print: "[1,2,3,5]" -- an string

var test_parse = JSON.parse(test_ids);
console.log(test_parse ); // will print: [1, 2, 3, 5] -- an integer array
```

just a guide on `JSON.parse()` vs `JSON.stringify()` link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.94).aspx
......

Comment: I ended up doing precisely that (See update 2). But I was getting NaN when trying to parse the strings in the array, so I had to use RegEx to extract the digits from the strings (see my answer)