# Convert encoded string back to normal

Tags: php, facebook, unicode, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unicode characters from JSON.stringify to real unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550094/unicode-characters-from-json-stringify-to-real-unicode-characters)

It seems facebook saves unicode strings in this format:

> \u10d8\u10de\u10dd\u10d5\u10d4\u10d7 \u10de\u10d0\u10e1\u10e3\u10ee\u10d8 \u10dc\u10d4\u10d1\u10d8\u10e1\u10db\u10d8\u10d4\u10e0 \u10d9\u10d8\u10d7\u10ee\u10d5\u10d0\u10d6\u10d4!

How can I convert it back to readable string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook Graph API returns [JSON](http://json.org) and the tool to use to make sense of that in PHP is [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/Answersge');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['company_overview']; // Outputs: იპოვეთ პასუხი ნებისმიერ კითხვაზე!
```