# How to get an integer from an utf8mb4 character ( aka "\u{D83D}\u{DE00}") in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding

I want to write a saslprep algorithm with php (I know there is a lib, I want to do it myself). One of my unit tests failes because the test vector  `"\u{D83D}\u{DE00}"` aka  fails to convert to code points (array of integer).

```
echo mb_ord("\u{D83D}\u{DE00}","UTF-32LE");
```

failes returning false

```
iconv("UTF-8","UTF-32LE","\u{D83D}\u{DE00}");
```

failes

The expected result is `128512`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output UTF-16? A little stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506988/output-utf-16-a-little-stuck)

Comment: I'll give it a try. I need utf32LE, the answer is about utf16BE.

Comment: Its not the answer, because it doesn't use the php's version of converting the codes. I used `\u{D83D}\u{DE00}` and they used `\uD83D\uDE00` which is basically a text string.

Answer (score 0):

At first, let's analyze `php` way of encoding:

```
<?php
$sp = "ař\u{05FF}€\u{D83D}\u{DE00}";
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() .
     '; internal_encoding: ' . mb_internal_encoding() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo $sp . ' (' . strval(mb_strlen($sp)) . ' chars in ' . 
                  strval(strlen($sp)) . ' bytes)' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$sp_array = mb_str_split($sp, 1, mb_internal_encoding() );
echo strval( sizeof($sp_array)) . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($sp_array as $char) {
    $cars = bin2hex($char);
    echo str_pad($cars, 8, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
        ' (' . strval(strlen($char)) . ' bytes) ' .
        str_pad(implode(",", mb_str_split($cars, 2) ), 12) .   // WTF-8
        str_pad('->' . strval(mb_ord($char)) . '<-', 10) . 
        ' 0x' . str_pad( dechex( mb_ord($char)), 6) .
        $char . "\t" . IntlChar::charName($char) . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**Output**: shows that surrogate code points are encoded as [WTF-8 (Wobbly Transformation Format − 8-bit)](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8):

```
71249878parsing.php
```

> ```
> Current PHP version: 8.1.2; internal_encoding: UTF-8
>
> ař׿€���� (7 chars in 18 bytes)
>
> 7
>       61 (1 bytes) 61          ->97<-     0x61    a     LATIN SMALL LETTER A
>     c599 (2 bytes) c5,99       ->345<-    0x159   ř     LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CARON
>     d7bf (2 bytes) d7,bf       ->1535<-   0x5ff   ׿
>   e282ac (3 bytes) e2,82,ac    ->8364<-   0x20ac  €     EURO SIGN
> f09f9880 (4 bytes) f0,9f,98,80 ->128512<- 0x1f600     GRINNING FACE
>   eda0bd (3 bytes) ed,a0,bd    -><-       0x0     ��
>   edb880 (3 bytes) ed,b8,80    -><-       0x0     ��
> ```

Now we can write the following functions and combine them to get desired number:

- `function CodepointFromWTF8`: [decode from well-formed `WTF-8` to code points](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/#decoding-wtf-8);
- `function CodepointFromSurrogates`: [decode from potentially ill-formed `UTF-16` to code points](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/#decoding-ill-formed-utf-16). The following formula should suffice for a *well-formed `UTF-16` surrogate pair*:
  `codepoint = 0x10000 + ((high - 0xD800) << 10) + (low - 0xDC00)`

**BTW:** Tested using `"ař\u{05FF}€\u{D83D}\u{DE00}"` sample string where *characters* are as follows (column `CodePoint` contains Unicode (`U+hhhh`) and `WTF-8` bytes and column `Description` contains surrogates in parentheses, if apply):

```
Char CodePoint                      Description
---- ---------                      -----------
   a {U+0061, 0x61}                 Latin Small Letter A
   ř {U+0159, 0xC5,0x99}            Latin Small Letter R With Caron
   ׿ {U+05FF, 0xD7,0xBF}            Undefined
   € {U+20AC, 0xE2,0x82,0xAC}       Euro Sign
   {U+1F600, 0xF0,0x9F,0x98,0x80} GRINNING FACE (0xd83d,0xde00)
     {U+D83D, 0xED,0xA0,0xBD}       Non Private Use High Surrogate
     {U+DE00, 0xED,0xB8,0x80}       Low Surrogate
```

### Edit

Here's full **simplified solution** (I don't follow [Userland Naming Guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php) arbitrarily mixing *snake_case*, *camelCase* and *PascalCase* rules, sorry):

```
<?php

function CodepointFromWTF8($ch) {
    $Bytes = str_split($ch);
    switch (strlen($ch)) {
    case 1:
        $retval = ord($Bytes[0]) & 0x7F;
        break;
    case 2:
        $retval = (ord(($Bytes[0]) & 0x1F) << 6) +
                  (ord($Bytes[1]) & 0x3F);
        break;
    case 3:
        $retval = ((ord($Bytes[0]) & 0x0F) << 12) +
                  ((ord($Bytes[1]) & 0x3F) << 6)  +
                   (ord($Bytes[2]) & 0x3F);
        break;
    case 4:
        $retval = ((ord($Bytes[0]) & 0x07) << 18) +
                  ((ord($Bytes[1]) & 0x3F) << 12) +
                  ((ord($Bytes[2]) & 0x3F) << 6)  +
                   (ord($Bytes[3]) & 0x3F);
        break;
    default:
        $retval = 0;
    }
    return $retval;
}

Function IsHighSurrogate ($cp) {
    return ($cp >= 0xD800 and  $cp <= 0xDBFF);
}

Function IsLowSurrogate ($cp) {
    return ($cp >= 0xDC00 and  $cp <= 0xDFFF);
}

Function CodepointFromSurrogates($Surrogates) {
    $cps = array();
    $cpsc = count($Surrogates);
    for ( $ii = 0; $ii < $cpsc; $ii+=1 ) {
        if ( ( IsHighSurrogate( $Surrogates[$ii]) ) and
             ( 1 + $ii ) < $cpsc and
             ( IsLowSurrogate( $Surrogates[1+$ii]) ) )
        {
            array_push($cps, 0x10000 + (
                ($Surrogates[$ii] - 0xD800) << 10) + ($Surrogates[$ii+1] - 0xDC00) );
            $ii+=1;
        } else {
            array_push($cps, $Surrogates[$ii] );
        }
    }
    return $cps;
}

$sp = "ař\u{05FF}€\u{D83D}\u{DE00}";
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion() .
     '; internal_encoding: ' . mb_internal_encoding() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo $sp . ' (' . strval(mb_strlen($sp)) . ' chars in ' . 
                  strval(strlen($sp)) . ' bytes)' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$sp_array = mb_str_split($sp, 1, mb_internal_encoding() );
echo strval( sizeof($sp_array)) . PHP_EOL;
$sp_codepoints = array();
foreach ($sp_array as $char) {
    $cars = bin2hex($char);
    $charord = mb_ord($char);
//     echo str_pad($cars, 8, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
//         ' (' . strval(strlen($char)) . ' bytes) ' .
//         str_pad(implode(",", mb_str_split($cars, 2) ), 12) .   // WTF-8
//         str_pad('->' . strval($charord) . '<-', 10) . 
//         ' 0x' . str_pad( dechex( $charord), 6) .
//         str_pad( gettype($charord), 8) .
//         $char . "\t" . IntlChar::charName($char) . 
//         PHP_EOL;
    if (gettype($charord) == "boolean") {
        $charord = CodepointFromWTF8($char);
    }
    array_push($sp_codepoints, $charord);
}
print_r($sp_codepoints);

$sp_codepoints_real = CodepointFromSurrogates($sp_codepoints);
print_r($sp_codepoints_real);
?>
```

**Result**: `71249878.php`

```
Current PHP version: 8.1.2; internal_encoding: UTF-8

ař׿€���� (7 chars in 18 bytes)

7
Array
(
    [0] => 97
    [1] => 345
    [2] => 1535
    [3] => 8364
    [4] => 128512
    [5] => 55357
    [6] => 56832
)
Array
(
    [0] => 97
    [1] => 345
    [2] => 1535
    [3] => 8364
    [4] => 128512
    [5] => 128512
)
```